# DOS VGA card vertical sync - how to check for blanking interval?

Tags: c++, vsync

I'm right now developing a game for ms dos in C++ (compiler: DJGPP) and need to test if the VGA card is currently in the vertical blanking interval. Is there a memory address I can just read? How can I check for this?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've done it, but here's a summary Iof the method I learned from André LaMothe's *Black Art of 3D Game Programming*:

You can write an interrupt service routine (ISR) that triggers when the Vblank interrupt fires. The Vblank interrupt is `0x0A` and typically reserved for IRQ 2. Back when I learned about it, it was a bit of a gamble as not all VGA handled this the same way. I'll stick to the bit settings that I learned at the time, but it's possible you may need to do some additional digging and tweaking depending on the manufacturer. Most of the time this means they clear on a 1 instead of a 0, etc.

To enable the Vblank interrupt:

- Install an interrupt handler at `0x0A`
- Enable the interrupt on the PIC. Usually this means clearing bit `d2` of the PIC IMR (interrupt mask register).
- Clear the vertical blank interrupt latch and the vertical blank interrupt enable bits (`d4` and `d5` respectively) in the Vertical Retrace End Register located at `0x11` of the CRT controller.

It's possible that other devices may generate interrupts on IRQ, so the ISR needs to first ensure that it's responding to actual VBlank interrupts and not something else. This can be done by checking bit `d7` of the VGAs input status register 0 at port `0x3C2`.

The other thing the ISR needs to do is reset the vertical interrupt latch at bit `d4` in the Vertical Retrace End Register in the CRT controller by setting said bit to 0.